# Non-elementary functions defined by power series

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Suppose $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ is a function defined by a convergent power series on its interval of convergence. Are there any simple criteria for the sequence $a_n$ which imply $f(x)$ is not an elementary function?

Comment: What is a "simple" criteria or an "elementary" function? Be more specific please.

Comment: The definition of an elementary function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function